# How would I write a pre-merge hook in Git?

Tags: git, merge, githooks

The question says it all. Is there a way to perform an action before a merge? I'm guessing there's a way to make use of a `pre-commit` hook, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Even if this question is more than 5 years old -- meanwhile any solution for this? For instance, I want people to be able to commit into their own, private branches whatever they want, but not merge code with terrible metrics into the develop or master branch...

Comment: Note: Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) actually does include a **pre-merge-commit** hook. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001118/6309)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try using the `prepare-commit-msg` hook. The second argument will be `merge` "if the commit is a merge or a `.git/MERGE_MSG` file exists". A non-zero exit status will abort the commit.

I don't think this will work with a fast-forward merge, since there won't be a commit message.

More info on hooks: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_prepare_commit_msg

Comment: This doesn't seem to be triggered when you do a git merge. To see this: put `exit 1` at the top of prepare-commit-msg and perform a merge commit.

Comment: Was it a fast-forward merge? If the merge doesn't trigger a commit message, it won't help.

Comment: Even for an actual merge with a commit (message) this is not triggered. I've tried with the test described above... Very happy to be proved wrong with an example, but please give this a test.

Comment: Is this possible even now? I have been trying to trigger a hook that would fire up before someone does a merge. I don't think its possible, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Works for me on non-fast-forward merges with git 2.18. `printf -- '%s\n%s\n' '#!/bin/sh' 'echo nope && exit 1' > prepare-commit-msg`

Comment: Works for me in a number of tests (in 2022, pre-merge-commit is supported in Git but not by all Git GUI clients, so this is still relevant)

Answer (score 28):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), no need for script wrapper, or prepare-message hook.

A new "**pre-merge-commi**t" hook has been introduced.

See [commit bc40ce4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc40ce4de612942e9a6a755f7432806ee095bd82), [commit 6098817](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6098817fd7f64209664c701df30096dc0f4fb876), [commit a1f3dd7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1f3dd7eb303d924f90da30808f7702869430321) (07 Aug 2019) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg).
See [commit f78f6c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f78f6c7e0ca91a48a4b519cc2cf1197d16810f7a) (07 Aug 2019) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f76bd8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f76bd8c6b132bdcefd547cb99cb832f433fee544), 18 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `git-merge`: honor `pre-merge-commit` hook

> `git-merge` does not honor the `pre-commit` hook when doing automatic merge
> commits, and for compatibility reasons this is going to stay.
>
> Introduce a `pre-merge-commit` hook which is called for an automatic merge
> commit just like pre-commit is called for a non-automatic merge commit
> (or any other commit).

The [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6098817fd7f64209664c701df30096dc0f4fb876/Documentation/githooks.txt#L106-L125) now includes:

> ### pre-merge-commit
>
> This hook is invoked by `git-merge`.
> It takes no parameters, and is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit.
> Exiting with a non-zero status from this script causes the `git merge` command to abort *before* creating a commit.
>
> The default 'pre-merge-commit' hook, when enabled, runs the 'pre-commit' hook, if the latter is enabled.
>
> This hook is invoked with the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR=:` if the command will not bring up an editor to modify the commit message.
>
> If the merge cannot be carried out automatically, the conflicts need to be resolved and the result committed separately (see `git-merge`).
> At that point, this hook will not be executed, but the '`pre-commit`' hook will, if it is enabled.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), the callers of `run_commit_hook()` learn if it got "success" because the hook succeeded or because there wasn't any hook.

See [commit a8cc594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8cc594333848713b8e772cccf8159196ea85ede), [commit 9f6e63b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f6e63b966e9876ca6f990819fabafc473a3c9b0) (07 Mar 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7431379](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7431379a9c5ed4006603114b1991c6c6e98d5dca), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f6e63b966e9876ca6f990819fabafc473a3c9b0): don't run post-hook logic on `--no-verify`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a minor bug introduced in [bc40ce4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc40ce4de612942e9a6a755f7432806ee095bd82) ("`merge`: `--no-verify` to bypass pre-merge-commit hook", 2019-08-07, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f76bd8c6b132bdcefd547cb99cb832f433fee544) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c86140027f4a0d2caaa3ab4bd8bfc5ce3c11c8a)), when that change made the `--no-verify` option bypass the `pre-merge-commit` hook it didn't update the corresponding `find_hook()` (later `hook_exists()`) condition.
>
> As can be seen in the preceding commit in [6098817](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6098817fd7f64209664c701df30096dc0f4fb876) ("`git-merge`: honor pre-merge-commit hook", 2019-08-07, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f76bd8c6b132bdcefd547cb99cb832f433fee544) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c86140027f4a0d2caaa3ab4bd8bfc5ce3c11c8a)) the two should go hand in hand.
> There's no point in invoking `discard_cache()` here if the hook couldn't have possibly updated the index.
>
> It's buggy that we use `"hook_exist()`" here, and as discussed in the subsequent commit it's subject to obscure race conditions that we're about to fix, but for now this change is a strict improvement that retains any caveats to do with the use of `"hooks_exist()`" as-is.

---

Warning: [Devin Rhode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565877/devin-rhode) reports (Nov. 2022) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102714/how-would-i-write-a-pre-merge-hook-in-git/58001118#comment131146088_58001118):

> I think I actually found a bug with the pre-merge-commit hook not running.
> See PR "[pre-merge-commit hook is not running](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1210)"

But [Pascal Jufer](https://github.com/paescuj) adds:

> I came to the conclusion that the pre-merge-commit hook is actually working as intended, which means this is not a bug.
> The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) states the following:
>
> > [...] is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit
> > [...]
>
> and
>
> > [...] If the merge cannot be carried out automatically, the conflicts need to be resolved and the result committed separately (see git-merge[1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6098817fd7f64209664c701df30096dc0f4fb876/Documentation/githooks.txt#L106-L125)).
> > At that point, this hook will not be executed, but the pre-commit hook will, if it is enabled.
>
> That means:
>
> - If there's a conflict like provoked in your reproduction (merge cannot be carried out automatically), the pre-merge-commit hook won't be called at all.
>   Understandably, after resolving the conflict and committing the changes, Git treats it like a normal commit and only calls the pre-commit hook:
>
>   ```
>   $ git merge remotes/origin/feature/make-eggs
>   $ git add readme.md
>   $ git commit
>   pre-commit hook
>   [main 26262e1] Merge remote-tracking branch 'remotes/origin/feature/make-eggs'
>   ```
> - When executing a "conflict-free" merge, there's no commit log message to obtain (fast-forward updates do not create a merge commit) which means the pre-merge-commit hook is skipped here as well.
> - The pre-merge-commit is getting called (also with custom `hooksPath`) as intended when a merge commit is generated, for example using `git merge --no-ff`:
>   $ git merge test --no-ff
>   pre-merge-commit hook
>   Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.

Comment: Nice!! Way better than my hacky wrapper.

Comment: Hey @VonC I think I actually found a bug with the pre-merge-commit hook not running: https://github.com/devinrhode2/git-pre-merge-commit-test/pull/1

Comment: @DevinRhode Thank you for this feedback. I have included your PR in the answer for more visibility, and will follow it.

Comment: Sounds like this hook is working correctly. You could remove call out in your answer, and just let people read comments. It's only called when you are prompted for a merge commit message. When you have to resolve conflicts, the normal pre-commit hook is called instead. See awesome write up from paescuj: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1210#issuecomment-1371726293

Comment: @DevinRhode I have edited the answer accordingly (an answer is more readable than comments). Let me know if I got everything.

Comment: Splitting hairs, but I think Pascals explanation works well in the context of that github thread, and I think something shorter and simpler would be more suitable for stackoverflow. Github links hopefully keep working for next 100 years, so I think summarizing + linking to his full comment is most sensible

Answer (score 1):

Another nice workaround would be to add a shell script, call it like you want,
then add these lines to the script:

```sh
git() {
    if [ "$1" == "merge" ]; then
        echo "seems to work like a charme"
    fi
    command git "$@"
}

git "$@"
```

Then make an

```
alias git="./my-pre-merge-script.sh"
```

Then you are good to go. You just added your own pre-merge hook.
I know, that you do not have access to whatever arguments git would pass to a real pre-merge hook, but you can prepare files or whatever you want to prepare for merge now; I personally am very happy with this approach: I spent 2 or 3 whole days to find something for pre-merge, then I had to go with the pre-commit-msg which I did not find accurate enough for my needs. This solves all my problems. Hope this helps anybody in the future.

Comment: -1. Not only is this ugly, it's not robust at all. `merge` isn't always the first argument to `git`: consider something like `git -c foo=bar merge foobar`.

Comment: It is an ugly hack indeed. However, thanks for the hint that merge does not have to be $1, however, you can still parse "merge" from the arguments list nevertheless!

Would have a better solution for pre-merge hooks?

Comment: That might be possible, but it's definitely pretty complicated. What if someone has a branch named `merge`? What if someone merges with `git pull` instead of `git merge`, or even with a custom git script? Your script needs to understand git to determine when the user is actually merging.

Comment: I am actually currently working on a huge script, involving git hooks. I need my own pre-git hook, which actually cares about git pull like you just said.

Also, I need to add special case handling for stuff like git merge --abort or git commit --amend... and there are quite endless possibilities of what users can do...

But sometimes, people might just be happy with a solution I provided above, for private/hobby projects, NOT for production projects in a company.
Thus, I think it is a bit harsh to downvote it instant, especially when you cannot provide a better alternative.

Comment: Also, whoever comes to the idea of calling a branch "merge" should find a new hobby imho.