# Disable Jasmine's fdescribe() and fit() based on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, codeship

`fdescribe()` and `fit()` are great for reducing noise when you're working on a subset of tests. I sometimes forget to change them back to `describe()`/`it()` before merging my branch into master. (It's okay to have them in separate branch while working on code - i.e. a pre-commit check wouldn't work for me.)

My CI environment is Codeship. Is there a solution to this problem that would fail the tests in Codeship if it came across any focused methods?

Using something like [no-focused-tests](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine/blob/master/docs/rules/no-focused-tests.md) would be okay. Any idea how to enable this rule as an error in Codeship and disable it locally?

Comment: `no-focused-tests` saved me so often before :). How about something like a pre-merge hook? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102714/how-would-i-write-a-pre-merge-hook-in-git)

Comment: Unfortunately the merge takes place on GitHub so unless it can be triggered as rule on the GitHub servers I don't think that would work. Thanks for the idea though! +1

Comment: I run jshint as part of my build it catches this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using something like no-focused-tests would be okay. Any idea how to enable this rule as an error in Codeship and disable it locally?

You could use a combination of environment variables and redefining the fdescribe/fit global functions:

1. `npm i --save cross-env`
2. package.json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "test": "jasmine",
     "test-safe": "cross-env FOCUSED_TESTS=off jasmine"
   },
   ```
3. disableFocusedTestsIfNecessary.js (included *after* jasmine defines its globals):

   ```
   if (process.env.FOCUSED_TESTS === "off") {
     console.log("Focused tests must be off");
     global.fdescribe = global.fit = function() {
       throw new Error("fdescribe and fit are disabled in this environment");
     };
   }
   else {
     console.log("Focused tests enabled");
   }
   ```
4. Tell codeship to run `npm run test-safe` instead of `npm run test`

Answer (score 7):

**Edit 14.11.19**:

To make things easier I created an installable package you can find at https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-jasmine

**Original post**:

If you're using TSLint and (like me) found that all the defocus and tslint-jasmine-noSkipOrFocus checkers are not working for you, I created a Gist for that: https://gist.github.com/djungowski/7d9126bb79970446b4ffeb5656c6bf1f

How to use:

1. Save Gist in a a folder called `TSLint/Rules` as `noJasmineFocusRule.js`
2. Add the Rules folder to your TSLint config: `rulesDirectory: 'TSLint/Rules'`
3. Enable option with `"no-jasmine-focus": true`

Comment: That's an elegant way of doing it. Thank's.

Comment: This works great with husky "pre-push" hook to prevent an `fdescribe` or `fit` from limiting your deployment pipeline automated tests. e.g. package.json

`"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "ng lint && ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
    }
  }`

Answer (score 3):

For those interested, if you are using jasmine and eslint, you can use this plugin to ensure no focused tests: https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine.

1. First install eslint globally `npm install -g eslint`.
2. Then install the eslint-plugin-jasmine library `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-jasmine`.
3. Create a `.eslintrc` file which would look something like this:

   ```
   {
     "rules": {
       "semi": 2
     },
     "plugins": ["jasmine"],
     "env": {
       "jasmine": true
     },
     "extends": "plugin:jasmine/recommended",
   }
   ```
4. Then you are ready to run the linter `eslint -c ./.eslintrc app.js`

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party.

I had a similar issue with my builds. We don't use ts / eslint so I just wrote a quick script to throw an error that would fail my dockerfile / build.

Here it is.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
files=$(find "./.." -type f -name '*.spec*')
errored=false

echo "Checking for focused tests"

for file in $files
do
    if grep -E "fdescribe|fit" $file; [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "-Focusing a test in the file $file"
        errored=true
    fi
done

if $errored; then
    echo "Some tests were focused"
    exit 1
else
    echo "No tests were focused"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution.  But it works for my needs.

To setup:

```
npm i lodash
npm i minimist
```

I call this from my gulp tasks:

```
node .\\build\\throwIfFocusedTest.js e2e/
node .\\build\\throwIfFocusedTest.js src/
```

throwIfFocusedTest.js:

```
const walkSync = require('./walkSync').default;
const _ = require('lodash');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv);
const fs = require('fs');

if (argv._.length !== 3) {
    throw 'expecting 1 command line argument';
}

const directory = argv._[2];

const files = walkSync(directory);
const scriptFiles = _.filter(files, f => f.endsWith('.js') || f.endsWith('.ts'));

const invalidStrings = [
    'fdescribe',
    'fit',
];

_.each(scriptFiles, fileName => {
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
    invalidStrings.forEach(is => {
        if (contents.includes(is)) {
            console.error(`throwIfFocusedTest: ${directory}: File contains ${is}: ${fileName}`);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });
});
console.log(`throwIfFocusedTest: ${directory}: No files contain: ${invalidStrings.join(', ')}`);
```

walkSync.js:

```
/**
 * From: https://gist.github.com/kethinov/6658166 
 */
exports.default = function walkSync(dir, filelist) {
    var fs = fs || require('fs'),
        files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    filelist = filelist || [];
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        var path = dir + file;
        if (fs.statSync(dir + file).isDirectory()) {
            filelist = walkSync(dir + file + '/', filelist);
        }
        else {
            filelist.push(path);
        }
    });
    return filelist;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to fail on when tests are marked for focus *or* skip (`fit` + `xit`), there's a relatively new Karma feature that solves the problem with no plugins.  Karma now supports a `failOnSkippedTests` config file / CLI option, which, per [the docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/5.2/config/configuration-file.html), causes "failure on tests deliberately disabled, eg fit() or xit()".