# Is it possible to force squashing commits before merge or not allow to merge if 'feature` branch has more than one commit?

Tags: git, github

so let's say I have two branches `develop` and `feature`, and `feature` branch is ahead on two extra commits.

I'm looking for some kind of following behaviour

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge feature
Error: make sure you squash all commits in `feature` branch before merging it
```

---

Maybe it's possible to configure on github side? To make github reject `git push origin develop` when `develop` has couple commits from `feature` branch.

---

**To make question more clear I will provide an example.**

```
// 1. working on a new feature
$ git checkout -b feature
$ git commit -m "foo"
$ git commit -m "bar"

// 2. merging to develop
// here I supposed to do `git rebase -i develop`
// but I forgot!!!!
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge feature

// 3. push to github
$ git push origin develop
```

I wish I would get some warning on step `2` or step `3`, because I forget to squash commits

Comment: Is this for yourself, or for other contributors to your repository?

Comment: For myself, but I would like to know if it's possible to setup globally as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the correct way to do this in github is to use pull requests and only merge the ones which look correct. I dont know if github allows pre-receive hooks, but a standalone git will, and for others you might try Gerrit.

You CAN make a local prepush hook, but since it runs on the committers computer, it is trivial to avoid.

This gives you pointers on how to do a local check before merge.

[How would I write a pre-merge hook in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102714/how-would-i-write-a-pre-merge-hook-in-git)

Comment: yeah, we use pull requests. But I would like to ensure that committer will squash commits. In particular case I wish to be sure that **I** don't push some rubbish _(like sequence of `wip` commits)_ to remote `develop`. I will take a look on `prepush` hooks.

Comment: yes prepush will disallow it ,but it will not prevent the user from making the error in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

use git rebase -i develop. Then you will be able to squash commits.

Comment: I know how to squash commits, I'm asking weather it's possible to force squashing?