# Make unable to branch merge [Lock for merge?]

Tags: git, branch

I was wondering, if it's possible to make branches unable to merge?
For Example: I have `master`, `branchA`, `branchB`. I'm currently working on branch `branchB` which is completetely different from the other branches. How to make this branch unable to merge with others?

My bad, if it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Completely different in what sense?

Comment: By that i mean all branches have simlar classes but implementations differs.

Comment: Same project but tailored to different clients?

Comment: yes. They all do share same POM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the branches are completely different then what you need is a completely separate repository, or a fork if you're using GitHub and the branch in question is at least similar to the other.

A rather ugly workaround would be a hook. There's no pre-merge hook but there is a [prepare-commit-msg hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460322/149998) (link to SO answer about pre-merge hooks) which receives an argument that would give you what you'd need to write a script that checks the name of the branch. It'd be ugly. I'm not 100% sure it would work. Realistically, you should go with the first option. If the two branches can never be merged they should be in separate repositories.

Comment: Sounds like a rocket science to me for now, but could you provide some 'prepare-commit-msg hook' using CLI? Or how it's done via IntelliJ ( if... that possible) Thanks

Comment: Your git project will include a sample script at this path: .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample