# Git: Remove folder content before merge to master

Tags: git, github

I'm wondering if and how I can achieve the following in Github. I have a Git repository called `Application`. I have a master branch with a folder called `Deployments` - this folder needs to be empty at all times, with no files in it.

Developers then create a branch from master and it's typical that developers add files to this `Deployments` folder and commit these files to their feature branch. Once developer is done with developing the feature, he will make a pull request to merge feature to master. For now, developer will manually clean up the content of the `Deployments` folder before making the PR. I would like to automate this solution to ensure that when the developer makes the pull request, some workflow will get triggered which will either remove the content of the `Deployments` folder or will notify the developer that there are files in that folder and merge cannot happen. Is this possible to achieve?

I read about `pre-commit` git hooks and I created one as per bellow shell script. It works fine but only partially - if I locally checkout master and will add files to `Deployments` folder, when I try to commit this, the commit will be rejected - that's great, however, if I'm on the feature branch I add the files and pushed those to feature branch (what is the expected developer workflow), I can then merge feature to master and files will end up in `Deployments` on master what is something I want to prevent.

Here is the pre-commit git hook:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DIR="Deployments"
BRANCH=$(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)

if [ "${BRANCH}" = "master" ]; then
    if [ "$(ls $DIR)" ]; then
        echo "The directory: $DIR - is not Empty and cannot be merged to Master"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "The directory: $DIR - is Empty"
    fi
else
    echo "on another branch: $BRANCH"
fi
```

Comment: Your use of this deployments folder is something I've never seen before.  What made you or your team choose this workflow?

Comment: You are looking for something like a `pre-merge` hook, but it does not exist in git directly. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102714/how-would-i-write-a-pre-merge-hook-in-git) answer it gives you a workaround.